# Asterisk forward call to number chosen by Twilio

Tags: twilio, asterisk

We are running Asterisk as our call dispatcher, but we would like to add some more logic with the programmable APIs offered by Twilio.

We can currently forward the call from Asterisk to Twilio, but in some case, we need to forward again the call to some SIP phone. However, we want to avoid the extra cost of handling the call through Twilio since it could be pretty long and it would become expensive for us.

Is there any way to tell back to asterisk which SIP phone should it re-forward the call to?

```
           |------|-----------|---------|
PRI------  | PBX  |--8 lines--|         |---------         
           |      |-----------|Asterisk |--------- 50 SIP phone
           |------|           |         |---------
                              |---------|
                                   || 
                                   || SIP 
                                   ||  
                              |---------|
                              |         |
                              | Twilio  | decides which SIP phone to forward the call
                              |         |
                              |---------|
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct solution for such case is sip redirect(301 code).

Unfortanly twilio API not support that, so no way.

Comment: Do other providers like Plivo support it? Could I write a number on some database and have asterisk reading it dynamically?

Comment: Some providers support, not think Plivio do. Yes, you can read numbers from db in asterisk,see func_odbc.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please give an example of providers?

Comment: Sending DTMF back to the asterisk with the number, wouldn't it be a solution?

Comment: Question about recommend tool, library, anything(provider) is prohibited on SO.